# What is the recommended Wordpress equivalent for drupal-views

Tags: wordpress, drupal-views

[CiviCRM](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/WordPress+and+CiviCRM+Integration) manual mentions X-Data Toolkit as a potential substitution to drupal-views. However X-Data Tookit has not been updated in years and its documentation is not available anymore.

What other plugin would you recomend as a replacement? A first Google search revealed :

- [TablePress](https://tablepress.org/) - does not support MySQL as data source, ev. one could write a plugin for TablePress
- [wpDataTables](http://wpdatatables.com/) – Not free, but supports MySQL and also has Charts
- [Wordpress Dynamic Tables](http://codecanyon.net/item/wordpress-dynamic-tables-input-from-xlsmysqlcsv/11189941) - Not free

Are there other alternatives I have not yet seen?

Answer (score 3):

Great question. Ideally you would create a bridge to the civicrm API and not hit the database directly.  I've floated it with two vendors:
https://wp-types.com/ and  http://pods.io/

You may find this useful: http://pods.io/docs/comparisons/compare-content-types/

Comment: I use wp-types on my standalone wordpress sites regularly and love it. I use it currently on my wordpress civi site but any civi related info is entered manually. It would be wonderful if they picked up some civi functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Michael McAndrew has just [posted](https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/pl/zk3zdts79tfimbsccqnc87zabh) a little hack he bodged together to get around the lack of views in wordpress.

1) it very much only solves his own particular use case

2) he is probably breaking lots of wordpress plugin development rules

3) there are many ways in which it would break down but he thought it worth sharing   in case people thought it was interesting / wanted to suggest ideas / additions / improvements / alternatives:

https://gist.github.com/michaelmcandrew/1f21e95d13b48c2bdf4d0b300a28c298.

Answer (score 0):

Work is happening to make https://github.com/mecachisenros/content-views-civicrm useful

Referenced here https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/pl/g9913yqt1tnmdesc85g6m34xph