# Been searching high and low... best approach for dispaying member information in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on a website that needs to display customized sets of membership information.

The kind of thing I’m going for:

- CiviCRM custom fields indicate that member  serves in a particular
  committee, and their role. Say, the Board of Directors.
- On the WordPress site, the Board of Directors page lists a grid of    members, and their roles.
- The site also shows those activities on a member’s profile page.

An example of the intended outcome: https://caims.ca/committee/executive/

I’ve been going through documentation to find a plausible approach, but I don’t see a clear path for the task as a whole. For each sub-task, there seem to be lots of possibilities, but no glowingly correct approach.

I’ve come across these possible steps, and possible tools:

1. Gathering “sets” of users (e.g., members who who are currently on the organization’s board )

   - smart groups
   - saved searches
   - tags
   - member directories
   - Drupal-esque views
2. Packaging those sets up for transfer to WordPress

   - exports
   - saved searches
   - custom-coded WordPress plugin
3. Displaying those sets in WordPress

   - shortcodes
   - Pods custom fields
   - Toolset custom fields

I’m thinking about finding a developer to do some custom code to link things up.

At this point, I imagine I would have come across a recognizable method if there was one. But it seems prudent to make sure I’m not missing a direct solution. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I am looking for very similar functionality, so would be interested to hear any updates. I wouldn't spam this post with a non-answer to your question but I cannot see any way to "follow" a post?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to contribute funding, it would be best to direct some funding to those pursuing creating Drupal Views like tools for Wordpress. Please see this thread [How do you approach "things that you would use Drupal views for" in WordPress?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/26952/how-do-you-approach-things-that-you-would-use-drupal-views-for-in-wordpress).