# Case status in front end of website?

Tags: wordpress, status

Is it possible to allow clients to log in and see limited data (e.g. status) of their cases?

Thanks!

Comment: What cms are you using?

Comment: Oops...forgot to add...I'm using WordPress. Thanks for asking.

Comment: In Wordpress I'm not sure there is currently a way to do this. There has been some work on the equivalent of drupal views (https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9439/what-is-the-recommended-wordpress-equivalent-for-drupal-views/9453) but you might also want to ask at chat.civicrm.org in the wordpress channel to get the latest on that.

Comment: Thanks so much. I'll go there to check.